# How to verify that node-fetch is called in typescript unit test?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, fetch

Hi I've a module that export some methods and I would like to test them with some unit tests. My project is based on typescript ^3.9.7 and it is installed jest ^26.1.0 and ts-jest ^26.2.0

One of these methods import node-fetch ^2.6.0 to be able to use window.fetch in node environment.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

export const fetchResponseFromRemoteFile = (
  remoteFileUrl: string
): Promise<Response> =>
  fetch(remoteFileUrl)
    .then(res => {
      return res.status === 200
        ? res
        : new Error(`failed to retrieve ${remoteFileUrl}`)
    })
    .catch(e => e)
```

In one of my test I wanna check that *fetchResponseFromRemoteFile* calls *fetch*

**approach 1**

```
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

jest.mock('node-fetch')

it('fetches', async () => {  
  const expectedResponse = { a: 1 }
  mocked(fetch).mockImplementation( () => <any>expectedResponse)
  ...
})


// mocked(fetch).mockImplementation( () => <any>expectedResponse)

TypeError: (0 , _utils2.mocked)(...).mockImplementation is not a function
```

**approach 2**

```
it('fetches', async () => {
  const expectedResponse = { a: 1 }
  ;(fetch as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(new Response(expectedResponse)))
  const remoteFile = await utils.fetchResponseFromRemoteFile(mockUrl)
  expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  expect(remoteFile.status).toEqual(200);
  expect(remoteFile.body).toEqual(expectedResponse);
  ...
})


// ;(fetch as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(new Response(expectedResponse)))

ReferenceError: Response is not defined
```

**approach 3**

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

jest.mock('node-fetch', () => jest.fn())

it('fetches', async () => {
  const expectedResponse = { body: { a: 1 } }
  const response = Promise.resolve(expectedResponse)
  fetch.mockImplementation(()=> response)
  ...
})


// fetch.mockImplementation(()=> response)

TypeError: _nodeFetch.default.mockImplementation is not a function
```

Ideas on what is going on here?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly unit test this, you should make use of dependency injection:

```js
export class FetchService {

  constructor(private readonly fetchInstance: any) {}

  public fetchResponseFromRemoteFile(
    remoteFileUrl: string
  ): Promise < Response > {
    this.fetchInstance(remoteFileUrl)
        .then(res => {
            return res.status === 200
                ? res
                : new Error(`failed to retrieve ${remoteFileUrl}`)
        })
        .catch(e => e);
  }
}
```

That way, you can just instantiate a mock and pass it on to your service while testing like so:

```js
const fetchMock = jest.Mock(); // Don't know the exact code but you know what I mean
const fetchService = new FetchService(fetchMock);

// Now you can do assertions on the 'fetchMock'.
```

Comment: where does `fetchInstance` get used?

Comment: Whoops, fixed! The method should use the `fetchInstance`.

Comment: do you think would it be possible to make a test without dependency injection also?

Comment: That's probably possible, I don't know how to do it on top of my head. In any case, making use of dependency injection is a good coding practice.